# What is Aegir Gold used for?

Tags: god-of-war-2018

In God Of War, Aegir Gold is basically most common resource - you can get a plenty just by roaming around Lake Of Nine. After finishing the game, I had around 1000 of this resource. Yet, I haven't found a single application to it, except selling it. Judging by the amount of Aegir Gold game gives you, it could be basic crafting material needed for everything, but I haven't found literally a single item requiring this resource to craft.

So, my question is - what's the purpose of Aegir Gold?

PS: I consider the possibility of this to be a persistent source of Hacksilver, yet it is really weird decision to give a player resource to sell instead of actual currency.

Comment: I've used pretty much all of my Aegir Gold to craft armour pieces.

The item I used it on first was a set of blue rare wrist armour, called Tyr's something.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [this materials guide](https://segmentnext.com/2018/04/24/god-of-war-materials-locations/), Aegir's Gold is:

> Used to upgrade armour and buy Runic Attacks.

This guide describes also all possible materials locations and uses, tradeables and special materials.

[This post on PlayStation Universe](https://www.psu.com/news/god-of-war-aegirs-gold-location/) goes the same way:

> You can then use it to upgrade gear.

Comment: Yeah it seems to be used for upgrading armour, but only Common (Green) and Rare (Blue). The Legendary (Purple) and Epic (Gold) need rarer materials. So it does become a source of income later in the game.